# Как правильно передать переменные из функции в СИ

Tags: c, функции, указатели

У меня есть функция main, где я создаю две переменные, и вызываю функцию input где через стандартный ввод, ввожу данные. Проблема в том что вывод в input верный, а main нет, что я делаю не так?

[image: main]

[image: head_input]

[image: input]

[image: output]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз у вас чистый C, в котором нет ссылок — передавайте через адреса.

```
input(int * rows, int* cols)
{
    ...
    scanf("%d",rows);
    ...
}


int main()
{
    ....
    input(&rows, &cols);
    ....
}
```

Так, как передаете вы — вы по сути передаете **копии** переменных.